# PHP Multiple Image Scripts On One Image Source

Tags: php, jquery, image

I have 2 different scripts for handling images:

The first one is  a watermark script for watermarking images on the fly:

```
$imgpath=$_REQUEST['filename'];
header('content-type: image/jpeg'); 
$watermarkfile="assets/img/logo_variations/logo_watermark_75.png";
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng($watermarkfile);
list($watermark_width,$watermark_height) = getimagesize($watermarkfile);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgpath);
$size = getimagesize($imgpath);
$dest_x = ($size[0] - $watermark_width)/2;
$dest_y = ($size[1] - $watermark_height)/2;
imagecopy($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height);
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($watermark);
```

So the image URL for a watermarked image is: `http://example.com/watermark.php?filename=assets/img/temp/temp_share.jpg` or since I'm using mod_rewrite to "pretty up" my URL: `http://example.com/watermark/assets/img/temp/temp_share.jpg`.

Works like a charm and my reason for doing so like this is because this is on a modeling website where I want to display the images without watermarks but I use a jquery script to change the image source of the image gets right clicked(assuming a user is trying to save the image).

The script only changes the source of any image with a class of `img-protected`.

I've written it to ignore any image with `watermark` in the URL so that it doesn't try to change the already watermarked image which would result in a url like: `http://example.com/watermark/watermark/img.jpg` which would result in a broken image. The other part is written to remove `http://example.com` from the original source so I don't end up with `http://example.com/watermark/http://example.com/img.jpg`.

```
$('.img-protected').on('mousedown', function (event) {
    if (event.which == 3) {
     if(this.src.indexOf("watermark") > -1) {
      return false;
     }
     else {
        src = this.src.replace('http://example.com/','');
        this.src = 'http://example.com/watermark/' + src;
        }
    }
});
```

All of this works exceptionally well until I added another image handling script:

I'm using [TimThumb.php](https://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/) which is an on the fly image resize script I use for creating gallery icons instead of uploading an icon and a full size image(this is how I wish to keep doing so as well).

The problem I am facing is this:

If I have an image that is being turned into a thumbnail using `TimThumb.php` which I renamed to `thumb.php` on my server the URL is `http://example.com/thumb.php?src=gallery/goth/industrial_brick/5361ae7de9404.jpg&w=350&h=500a=c&s=1&f=11` which gives me an icon for `5361ae7de9404.jpg`.

All of my icons have a class of `img-protected` which means on right click the above URL is going to be changed to the watermarked one.

This is where it fails.

The outputed URL when right clicked is `http://example.com/watermark/http://www.example.com/thumb.php?src=gallery/goth/industrial_brick/5361ae7de9404.jpg&w=350&h=500a=c&s=1&f=11` which results in a broken image.

I manually tried making the URL into `http://example.com/watermark/thumb.php?src=gallery/goth/industrial_brick/5361ae7de9404.jpg&w=350&h=500a=c&s=1&f=11` to see if that would change anything but it still results in a broken image.

What I need is to be able to also watermark the generated icons from `thumb.php` using `watermark.php`.

Is there a way to combine these two scripts or a workaround to make this work?

I'm at a complete loss here.

**EDIT:** I am fully aware that advanced users can still acquire the non watermarked image since it's already been downloaded to there device, but I don't expect a high volume of users to visit this particular website as this is simply a local models portfolio.

Comment: Either try if it works already by requesting i.e. `http://example.com/watermark.php?filename=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fthumb.php%3Fsrc%3Dgallery%2Fgoth%2Findustrial_brick%2F5361ae7de9404.jpg%26w%3D350%26h%3D500a%3Dc%26s%3D1%26f%3D11`, or adapt your "watermark script" to not only expect the parameter `filename` but alternatively another which then executes your **thumb.php** accordingly.